# $\alpha''(t)=0$ what can we say about $\alpha$

Tags: differential-geometry

A parameterized curve $\alpha(t)$ has the property that its second derivative $\alpha''(t)=0,\forall t\in I$ where $I$ is some unspecified interval. What can be said about $\alpha$?

I get the feeling that all we can say is that it isn't infinitely differentiable, since any regular parameterized curve can be reparameterized to be unit-speed, this gives me the impression that having constant velocity is perfectly fine for any curve, hence $\alpha$ isn't limited in terms of what it looks like, right?

Comment: Uh oh, I think I just realized a big problem with what I just said. It's unit velocity actually, aka, $|\alpha'(t)|=1$ isn't it

Comment: The curve $\alpha$ will be a line.

Comment: @Zilliput Oh that makes perfect sense when I visualise it, since a curve means the tangent line changes, and tangent line changing means changing second derivative

Comment: How many dimensional curve is that?

Comment: How is a curve with $\alpha''(t)=0$ for $t \in I$ _not_ infinitely differentiable  over $I$? A derivative can be zero and still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, we have $$\alpha ''(t)=0\iff \alpha '(t)=c_1\iff \alpha(t)=c_1t+c_2$$

where, $c_1$ & $c_2$ are constants of integration

thus we can say that $\alpha(t)$ is a linear function of parameter $t$ i.e. it represents a family of straight lines.

Comment: I guess that puts the differential in differential geometry :). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.